# Modify TypedArray position for n-dimensional matrix

Tags: c++, matlab, operator-overloading, mex

I want to modify values for a matrix that I previously don't its size:

```
ArrayFactory factory;
std::vector<size_t> position = {3, 14, 2, 23};
Array mat_data = factory.createArray<double>({30, 30, 30, 30});
Reference<TypedArray<double>> temp = mat_data[position[0]]; //fails here
for (int i = 1; i < positions.size(); ++i)
    mat_temp = mat_temp[positions[i]];
mat_temp[positions.back()] = getMyValue(position);
```

This gives me the following error:

> Not enough indices provided

I know that I'm able to do this:

```
mat_data[3][14][2][23] = getMyValue(position);
```

But I can't hard code this, because I don't know the size of `position` when the algorithm starts.

---

Actual solution removing the `private` that hides `ArrayElementRef(ArrayElementRef<is_const_ref>&& rhs) MW_NOEXCEPT` on `ArrayElementRef.hpp`:

```
ArrayElementRef<false> getElementRef(ArrayElementRef<false> elem, std::vector<size_t>& position, size_t pos) {
    if (pos >= position.size() - 1)
        return std::move(elem);
    return getElementRef(elem[position[pos]], position, ++pos);
}
```

And then:

```
ArrayFactory factory;
std::vector<size_t> position = {3, 14, 2, 23};
Array mat_data = factory.createArray<double>({30, 30, 30, 30});
ArrayElementRef<false> mat_temp = getElementRef(mat_data[position[0]], positions, 1);
mat_temp[position.back()] = getMyValue(position);
```

But, removing this `private` is not desirable...

Comment: Why does this carry the `matlab` tag?

Comment: These are Matlab classes.

Comment: You problably need to create the array using `new` instead of `[somesize]`. The latter needs to know the size at compile time. Something like `Reference<TypedArray<double>> temp= new Reference<TypedArray<double>>[position[0]]` and then a copy.

Comment: Please try this (I don't have MATLAB on hand to try it out right now): use `auto temp = mat_data[position[0]]`. Then also change the loop to go to `positions.size()-1`, and correct the variable name that goes from `temp` to `mat_temp`.

Comment: `auto temp` does not work because `ArrayElementRef` is private.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand that reason. `mat_data[position[0]]` returns an object of some type. You can always catch such an object, no? I think your fails because you are casting it to `Reference<TypedArray<double>>`. Using `auto` you don't cast at all. But I have no idea of the types involved internally here, the documentation is very scarce still, it's a fairly new API.

Comment: Yes! The problem is the cast! `detail::castTo`. It makes `Impl` `shared_ptr` be deleted.

Comment: By now, I'm trying to solve setting `ArrayElementRef` to `public`... I don't know what I would put in the place of `Reference<TypedArray<double>>`.

Comment: I might play around a bit too with this tonight. Interesting problem! If you have a license, I'd recommend you try contacting the MathWorks customer service with this. I have not seen any examples online that show how to index into arrays with arbitrary dimensionality. It's all two-dimensional examples!